# Generating a dynamic radial background

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a website and wanted to add a background where the user could choose the color.

What I wanted is to add a kind of a radial light shadow, instead of having a flat color on the background.

I've found this image that has what I have in mind, maybe it can help you understand what I am trying to achieve: [Red background with a slightly lowered  centered radial shadow.](http://typenuts.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/helveti-tweet.jpg)

At the same time, I'm trying to create this effect in SVG, since what I have in mind is having a background color, let's say red (just like the image), then the radial shadow on top the HTML content.

Comment: I think you'll find this site useful : http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'\-moz\-linear\-gradient\%28left\%2C\%20rgba\%28248\%2C80\%2C50\%2C1\%29\%200\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28241\%2C111\%2C92\%2C1\%29\%2050\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28246\%2C41\%2C12\%2C1\%29\%2051\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28240\%2C47\%2C23\%2C1\%29\%2071\%25\%2C\%20rgba\%28231\%2C56\%2C39\%2C1\%29\%20100\%25\%29\%3B'

Comment: It really was! I'm just tweaking it and I'll post an answer, may be useful for someone later.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure you would want to do this in SVG.... though. it creates.... load on the browser unnecessarily. unless you plan on doing something with it.

Comment: and i also think you mean dichormatic? or Dynamic? also that site is also a good place to start if you want to do something similar, i suggest predefined colors

Comment: About the SVG format I thought it would be better, since it would be scalable and wouldn't have problems with the window size. On the site you suggested I remembered about the radial-gradients so the SVG use is not what I look anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the effect I was searching for, this is pretty close to the answer (I did not tweak the position of the background, as I wanted slightly lowered, but that is not important):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        /* Background solid color */
        background: rgba(255, 127, 0, 1);

        /* Old Browsers */
        background-image: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

        /* FF3.6+ */
        background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 100%);

        /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20)));

        /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 100%);

        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 100%);

        /* IE 10+ */
        background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 100%);

        /* W3C */
        background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 100%);

        /* Fixes to set the radial shadow fixed */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;

        /* Fix to set the radial shadow the height of the window */
        min-height: 100vh;
    }       
</style>

<body> </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

I've been working with the backgrounds and found the answer I wanted in the beginning:

```
background-image:
  radial-gradient(
    50vw 80vh at 50vw 80vh,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 100%
  );
```

Explanation:

- The first `50vw 80vh` were to set the radial gradient with 50% of the virtual width of the window and 80% of the virtual height;
- The second `50vw 80vh` were to set the radial gradient 50% of the virtual width from the left and 80% of the virtual height from the top;
- The first `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%` sets the color of the radial gradient from 0% to 50% of the gradient size completely transparent;
- The second `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 100%` sets the color of the radial gradient from 50% (since the last color-stop is at 50%) to 100% of the gradient size black slightly transparent (1/4, or 25%, to be exact);

Hope I didn't said anything wrong and that this could be helpful for someone.